# cursor values in SQL query

Tags: sql, plsql

```
I have two tables  
1.
shiv_tab_col

TABLENAME     | COLUMNNAME
--------------------------  
 SER_SHIV_SYN | TABLENAME    
 SER_SHIV_SYN | COLUMNNAME


AND SER_SHIV_SYN

TABLENAME   | COLUMNNAME
--------------------------  
 A          |  B  
 E          | NULL  
NULL        | NULL  
NULL        | NULL  
NULL        | NULL  
NULL        | NULL  

BUT WHEN I M TRYING TO RUN THE BELOW CODE IT IS GIVING ME '0' AS VALUE OF TNAME

DECLARE
tname varchar(20):=null;

 CURSOR C1 IS
    SELECT  *
    FROM SHIV_TAB_COL;


BEGIN
    for rec in C1

loop
    select count(*) into tname from (select nvl(rec.columnname,1)b from ser_shiv_syn) where b ='1';
    dbms_output.put_line(tname);
    dbms_output.put_line(rec.columnname);
END LOOP;
END;
```

Actually i m looking to count the no. of null values in each column which will be stored  in variable TNAME
for first column it should give 4
for 2 column it should give 5

Comment: Please improve formatting, this is really tough to read. And please add at least the value for TNAME you expected. It is really hard to improve/correct something when you don't know the desired outcome.

Comment: Sorry for being harsh, but your code makes very little sense. It doesn't look at all like you know what you are doing, more like a wild copy-paste-session with a bit of trial and error.

Comment: When you execute
select count(*) into tname
then it's reasonable that you get
tname='0'. You can't join data in a table with the names of tables/columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing now is counting all empty occurrences of the column `COLUMNNAME` in the table `shiv_tab_col`. Which is 0 (you already found that out).

The solution is a bit more complicated, you need dynamic SQL to accomplish what you want to do:

```
declare
  l_count pls_integer;
begin
  for r_cur in (
    select columnname
    from shiv_tab_col
  )
  loop
    execute immediate 
      'select count(1) from ser_shiv_syn where '||r_cur.columnname||' is null' 
    into l_count;
    dbms_output.put_line(l_count);
    dbms_output.put_line(r_cur.columnname);
  end loop;
end;
/
```

Comment: Your query determined if the string 'TABLENAME' is null (it isn't) and if 'COLUMNNAME' is null (it isn't either). Your query is based on the wrong assumption that Oracle will actually translate the string 'TABLENAME' to mean "the column TABLENAME from the table ser_shiv_syn".

Answer (score 1):

Just a small hint: For your cursor use this:

```
SELECT  column_name 
FROM    all_tab_columns
WHERE   table_name = 'SER_SHIV_SYN'
```

Instead of shiv_tab_col.

This table is automatically updated and it's always in there. 
It also has field type, size, etc. Everything and more for 0 cost. Win-Win.